# How do you create seed oil in Minecraft Forestry 1.6?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I cannot figure how to extract oil from seeds in order to put it into a can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Put seeds or nuts in a squeezer](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=crafting:squeezerrecipes&s[]=seed&s[]=oil)

Comment: The trick is that it needs a lots of seed to extract oil and the adequate container (wax in my case)

Comment: Yes, 50 seeds per bucketsworth.

Comment: Additionaly, if there was another liquid than seed oil in the squeezer you need to empty it in order to squeeze seed oil (by removing/ replacing the squeezer)